# Setting up team and development processes

Tags: c#, .net, process

#### Based upon your experience

If you was given the opportunity to set up the development processes for a small development team.

**Please detail**

- The things you would implement, tools, documents, methodology.
- And how you would implement these?

**I wish to implement the following:**

- Source Control
- Bug tracking database
- Formal Spec templates
- Code Reviews
- Coffee cup meeting (simple quick informal meetings over coffee :) )
- Strict Coding convention

Please keep in mind this would be for a C# .NET focused environment.

Answer (score 4):

If you plan on purchasing, or already have purchased, MSDN subscriptions, there is a major change in licensing that plays out in your favor for Team Foundation Server 2010.  Server licensing is now included with MSDN, and you are provided with one CAL per subscription.  More licensing details are available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2009/10/20/tfs-2010-server-licensing-it-s-included-in-msdn-subscriptions.aspx).

Team Foundation Server will cover almost all of your needs in one package.  I am very preferential to using as few tools to complete a job as possible, which is one of the reasons I recommend that you look into using Team Foundation Server, as well.

Some notes into your specific requirements:

- **Source Control** - One of the primary functions of Team Foundation Server.  It works well and easily integrates with AD Groups.  We have security groups set up by roles per project and also for roles across projects.  A company developer will be a part of the "Developer" SG and the specific SGs that he/she are involved in.  This allows us to give them full access to the projects that they are working on and read access to all projects.  The system has the benefit of contractors not belonging to a generalist development group - effectively bucketing them into projects.
- **Bug Tracking Database** - Integration with source control is a definite advantage.  By using one package, you have an built in relationship between work items and changesets (which you can further enforce by requiring changesets are only created in the context of work items).  Work item relationships are very nice - and vary, depending on your template choice.  Both Microsoft's SCRUM and Agile templates are well thought out, and have served our needs quite well, to date.
- **Formal Specification Templates** - There are a couple of ways to approach this.  You could create a specific work item type for each template and prepopulate some of the content, or if you wanted a more traditional approach, you could store document templates within the project's Document tree (which is, effectively, a document library on the Team Project Portal site).
- **Code Reviews** - Basic functionality like Annotate (or Blame, if you prefer) are built in.  Diff Tools are provided, as well - plus you can switch out the diff tools for others if you do not like what ships with it.  (Personally, I use [DevArt's CodeCompare](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/) .)  As for the actual review process, I am a fan of [TeamReview](http://teamreview.codeplex.com/).
- **Strict Coding Conventions** - StyleCop is a must, in my opinion.  As such, I also believe that ReSharper is a must, as well.  Providing conventions is one thing, but being able to visibly put them in front of the user is another.  Using something like [StyleCop for ReSharper](http://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com/) will provide real-time feedback on violations of policies.  Anything that you want to add that isn't a part of StyeCop can be created via custom rules, and you can actually put the ReSharper configuration for SCFR in TFS, so that it is shared by the team.

Bonus items that you get that you did not explicitly mention:

- **Build Management** - The build tools in Team Foundation Server 2010 are completely overhauled.  Now, builds are defined as workflows using Workflow Foundation, but still can be manually manipulated for more complex build scenarios  Gated check-ins, often referred to as "buddy builds" help keep bad code out of the trunk.
- **Test Management** - Testers can benefit from the streamlined testing tools in Visual Studio 2010.  Automation of CodedUI tests, and the Test Lab Management tools are major strides in the evolution of Visual Studio.  Having a tester be able to capture the state of the machine and automatically insert it into a work item is brilliant, and long overdue.  Plus, if you end up using the Test Lab tools, actually being able to capture a snapshot of the VM at the moment of the crash is just pure gravy.
- **Collaboration** - Even if you don't plan on using it at first, the Team Project Portals that are created for each Team Project are ripe with opportunity for collaboration.  Just for document management and project wikis alone, it is worth its weight in gold.
- **Reporting** - The reports vary with the templates that you use, but most templates have the type of reports that management care about ready to go.  Adding new reports is fairly simple, due to the way that the TFS team has presented data in the cube, as well.  A little SSRS knowledge will have you creating detailed custom reports in no time, at all.
- **Planning** - You do not mention what type of methodology you are using - but the Agile template has some really nice sprint planning tools built in.  You literally launch a sprint planning worksheet from Visual Studio, which opens in Excel, and any changes you make are reflected in TFS.  Really works great for a group planning session.
- **Support** - This is one of the most important factors to me.  Having all of the above in a single package also means that I only need to go to one vendor for support.  It is invaluable to me to be able to have one phone number to call in the rare occasion that something does go wrong, and know that I have the support incidents to cover it already paid for, thanks to my MSDN subscription.

All that being said, TFS does have a bit of a learning curve.  Installation and setup are actually quite simple, assuming that you follow the documentation.  The learning curve comes from the fact that there is so much to do with TFS.  You might not use all of the features, so the amount of time you actually need to spend learning might vary.  The native integration with Visual Studio (and Office) do provide a seamless feel, though, that should translate well to the developers using the system.

Answer (score 2):

**Source Control:**  For a .NET environment, Team Server is good stuff.  If you want a free solution, I like Mercurial.

**Bug Tracking:**  FogBugz (of course :)

**Spec Templates:** I think defining these should be a collaborative process between the development team and business units.  Start with a very light framework and let them evolve, don't prescribe a massive document that includes information no one ever uses.

**Code Reviews:**  Peer programming time offers this in abundance.  Call out good practices to the team- don't use it as a way to humiliate developers in public.

**Meetings:** I'm an Agile kind of guy, so meetings (standups) should be brief, to the point, and happen every day at the same time.

**Coding Conventions:**  Again, if you have capable developers you shouldn't have to prescribe strict conventions.  Agree as a team on basic conventions and address friction points as necessary.

Comment: +1 as you've got a very similar perspective to what I would write; 2 things though - Continuous integration would be a nice addition to the list and spec templates will prove useless/a hindrance over time for any work of complexity (there is no substitute for interpersonal skills or an excellent business analyst)

Comment: I need to investigate all possible source control systems, I was leaning towards SVN + VisualSVN

Answer (score 1):

If your team can foot the bill for Team Foundation Server, you'll have most of what you want in one convenient package.

- **Source Control**: Changeset-based configuration control system with full branching support.
- **Bug tracking database**: Work items - configurable, including bug tracking and reports.
- **Formal Spec templates**: Work items - configurable, including requirements (CMMI), scenarios (Agile), custom types, etc.
- **Code reviews**: Work items - track your reviews just like any other TFS piece of work. A review work item ships with the CMMI process template.
- **Strict coding convention** - I've heard of people [integrating StyleCop with their check-in policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327324/enforce-custom-stylecop-rules-for-a-checkin-policy-on-tfs).

As for coffee cup meetings, you won't need a tool for that. :)

Comment: StyleCop sounds very interesting indeed, this is the first I've heard of it.

Comment: Here's a link. It took me a while to get accustomed to it, but I've found it to be valuable. It ships with a grundle of style rules, and is extensible if you have the inclination to try. (http://stylecop.codeplex.com/)